# Face dots show for some invisible faces anyway, despite x-ray is off

Tags: 3d-view

[image: face dots show on invisible faces]

First, face center option in viewport overlay is on.

Then, as shown on the right side of the first image above, Blender 2.82 shows face dots for visible faces, but also extend the display to some invisible faces, despite x-ray is turned off. This adds extra difficulty to work with complex models. Is there a way to turn this "extension" of face dots display off?

Or, can I achieve same display result for face dots as shown in the second image, in Blender 2.8X?

[image: what's like in 2.79]

Comment: Since it is not displaying in  vertex mode, I see a chance to be accepted in Bug Tracker. Thank you

Comment: This only happens in orthographic mode, correct? If it doesn't then you likely have incorrect clipping values that cause problem calculating the depth buffer.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yes it only happens in orthographic mode...Is this a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, how can I turn it off?